# How to retrieve the previous Model in the POST in MVC C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model

I have a View called MyVideos in which there is a list of videos and a list of comments. This is its `IActionResult`:

```
MyModel model = new MyModel();
model.videos = DB.GetVideos();
model.listOfComments = DB.GetComments();
model.comment = String.Empty;
return View(model);
```

I would like an user to upload a comment, and this is how I did it:

cshtml

```
    <form method="post" action="SubmitComment">
        <div class="form-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" id="exampleFormControlTextarea1" asp-for="comment"></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
```

cs

```
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SubmitComment(MyModel model)
    {
        string videoId = ...
        DB.uploadComment(videoId, model.comment);
        model.videos = DB.GetVideos();
        model.listOfComments = DB.GetComments();
        return View("MyVideos", model);
    }
```

As you see, I am forced to retrieve `model.videos` again when I am just uploading a comment. Is there a way to retrieve the old model's data here? Thank you.

Tried to search for similar questions without success. I am sorry if it's naive.

Comment: The solution is depend on what the `videos` and `listOfComments` are. if you will include code of these properties this might be help to understand what you are looking for. In case data takes too much place will be better to use `id` related to the loaded data (like `videoId`) and don't data themself.
The last sentence is related to data integrity too.

Comment: @Jackdaw thank you so for your answer. I actually don't have performance issues (I was already doing as you suggested) but I was just curious if something like that could have been possible to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about creating an action to retrieve the  model's data  and  showing the MyVideos view?

Then you can DB.uploadComment(videoId, model.comment);, and return RedirectToAction that action. In that action you retrieve the old model's data  and new data. Then you don't need to  retrieve model.videos again when just uploading a comment.

You can read [Processing the POST Request](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-mvc-app/controller-methods-views?view=aspnetcore-7.0#processing-the-post-request) to know more.